# Can I use a ClearCase snapshot view as a DocRoot on a web server?

Tags: deployment, clearcase, web-deployment

I have been asked by my manager to come up the pros and cons of using a ClearCase snapshot view as a docRoot to a web server. Deployments to different environments in this case will be just an update to the view.

Ofcourse there are other considerations about how to control on what to update.

Hence my question to all the experts out there: has anyone done this before? what do you guys think about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cons**:

Using a VCS for deployment on a production server is usually considered a **bad practice** because:

- you need to install and administer another component (here ClearCase) which isn't necessary to *run* your app
- you need to manage permission access (usually, a production server has very limited access compared to dev, SIT -- System Integration Test -- or UAT -- User Acceptance Test -- servers)
- ClearCase snapshot views can have various update glitches (hijacked files, config spec selection errors, ...) that you need to take into account.

**Pros**:

Since it is a web server, it is conceivable to use a VCS as a deployment tool considering the deployment process is fairly straight-forward (just copying some files without changing the structure).
It can be used to facilitate:

- quick fixes committed back to the VCS (since your are already in a ClearCase snapshot view, you can "`cleartool co -c "quick fix" aFile`", change it, and "`cleartool checkin`" it back.
- revision identification (`cleartool ls` will give you precisely the element selection rules used to display those files)

---

All in all, I really prefer keeping VCS for *development* environment, and uses other process for deployment.
It not only feels cleaner, it also remains compliant with a strong separation between dev and prod environments.

Comment: one good thing about Snapshot views (w.r.t ClearCase) is that it does not need to interact with ClearCase server at all. Only at the time of the deployment (which is basically a Cleartool update) the view needs to get an update from the server.

Comment: For some reason, I have always thought that using a version control system might be a bad idea. I am not sure why.

Comment: @HiteshSavla true, but you need to be careful with the files you are modifying then, because there will become hijacked and will need to be reconciled if you before the next update (or you will need to do a `cleartool update -overwrite`)

Comment: @HiteshSavla it is generally considered a bad idea to access dev referential (like a VCS like ClearCase) from a prod environment.

Comment: Makes sense. What are your thoughts on Rollback? Considering you are doing your deployment using Labels. All the rollback really will be is to change your config spec to now look at the older Release label. I still think it will be a bad idea. I just need to be convincing enough to my boss about why. I know compliance is a good point here.

Comment: @HiteshSavla if possible, for webapp I like to do a deployment in a separate directory per revision deployed. Rollback? I just change a symlink. Again, no need to mess with a config spec of a VCS, with potential errors during the update. The idea behind a rollback is: "I had something that worked. I tried to deploy something new that didn't work. Let's go back to what worked before. Pronto!".

Comment: @HiteshSavla And updating a snapshot view with ClearCase is the opposite of "pronto!". Everything is so slooow with ClearCase. Updating a symlink? Lightning fast (even though other operations might be needed to complete said rollback)